# Variables not shown while filtering a DataFrame

Tags: r

I have the following DataFrame:

```
            City     n
          (fctr) (int)
1        Branson     4
2      Calistoga     3
3         Dallas     1
4  Daytona Beach     1
5      Las Vegas     1
6    Los Angeles    15
7        Memphis     1
8          Miami     1
9  New York City     2
10  Philadelphia     1
11       Phoenix    59
12     San Diego     1
13       Seattle     4
```

I tried filtering my df in the following way.

```
mask <- (df$n > 1)
df[mask]
```

But I get this error:

```
Source: local data frame [13 x 2]

Variables not shown: NA (NULL), NA (NULL)
```

I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: `df[mask,]` - you want to filter rows not columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is the right answer. I was trying to filter the columns instead of the rows.

```
df[mask,]
```